# Android notification to open DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I Have a class that `extends DialogFragment`. I want to make my app do a `Notification` and when the user selects the notification, opens the `DialogFragment` with its layout and some data. 
Is there are any source code to do this?

Hope anyone helps me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer, you can't open a dialog via onclick of a notfication, there is no way in android, what you can do is,

to Start activity themed as Dialog

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

now when  startActivity() is called, its displayed like dialog, so moove everything you want to display here and call this activity by pending intent.

Also to add further, to make sure your activity wont appear in recent task list you can add the following  `excludeFromRecents=true`

Comment: I know this site, but I'm searching for how to open 'DialogFragment' and it is Fragment not Activity. Are you got my mean?

Comment: I changed my answer, I got it wrong at first, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the pendingintent open up one of your activities and have your activity be complete transparent and just open a dialog.

```
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context,YourActivityClassHere.class);
notifyIntent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//UNIQUE_ID if you expect more than one notification to appear
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(SimpleNotification.this, UNIQUE_ID, 
            notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: My Target is not (Activity), its (DialogFragment) is this will work with DialogFragment?